# AngularJS - Bootstrapping data into a service on page load

Tags: angularjs, bootstrapping, angularjs-service

In an angularjs app, I am attempting to use a custom service to hold the app's main data, "items". However, I would like to bootstrap the data into the service upon the initial page load, in order to avoid a separate ajax request to the server to get it. What would be cleanest way to go about doing this?

Here is a snippet of my service for reference:

```
app.factory('items', function() {
    var itemsService = {},
        items = [];

    itemsService.list = function() {
        return items;
    };

    itemsService.add = function() {
        /* ... */
    };

    return itemsService;
});
```

And on the backend I am using node.js + expressjs + jade, so I would be injecting the data into the page using:

```
!{JSON.stringify(items)}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Better answers in original - [How to bootstrap data as it it were fetched by a $resource service in Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451864/how-to-bootstrap-data-as-it-it-were-fetched-by-a-resource-service-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your bootstrapped data from the server into a global JavaScript variable.  Have your service assign `items` to that global variable (or copy the data into `items`).

Comment: that was what i was thinking, but where should that assignment/copy occur within my code? Because simply doing it within the `app.factory` call to create the service, replacing `items = []` with `items = window.bootstrappedData` (where bootstrappedData is the global javascript variable) does not seem to work.

Comment: I would put the assignment/copy where you tried.  The only thing I can think to check is to make sure the JavaScript code that assigns the data to global variable `bootstrappedData` is executing before Angular.

Comment: turns out was just a small error on my part, the script tag I placed the data into had its type attribute set to `js/data` so it was not being executed as javascript. >_<

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
app.run(['items', function (items) {
   items.load();
}])
```

This presumes your `items` service has a `load` function (or something like it) that does the actual Ajax work using either $http or $resource.

Comment: but then if I am just calling my `load()` function, I am still just making that ajax request to load the data instead of using the inline javascript injected array of `items`, or am i totally misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: I am assuming that a "load" function would perform an Ajax request whose success function would assign the new data set into the inline "items" variable.  So "load" doesn't return anything; its only purpose is to get data into your internal "items" array.